# VPN connection between routers

Tags: networking, router, vpn, asus

Trying to set VPN between home and work routers. VPN connection is established and both sides can ping each other routers:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.0.0 (Work network)
```

and

```
ping 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.1.0 (Home network)
```

But it is not possible reach other PC's inside of network on both sides:

From PC in Work to PC in Home network:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.100 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.0.1]
  2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.8.0.6
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

and

From PC in Home to PC in Work network:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.0.96 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     3 ms    10 ms     *     192.168.1.1
  2     3 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.8.0.1
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

More configuration details:

Home:

```
OpenVPN client
192.168.1.0/24
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
default         78.61.155.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun14
78.61.152.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
78.61.155.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
239.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
```

Work:

```
OpenVPN server
192.168.0.0/24

Interface Type: TUN
Respond to DNS: Yes
Advertise DNS to clients: Yes
Push LAN to clients: Yes
Direct clients to redirect Internet traffic: No (as each site uses their own internet access for external traffic)
Manage Client-Specific Options: Yes
Allow Client <-> Client: Yes
Allow only specified clients: Yes

Allowed Clients:
Common name: client
Subnet : 192.168.1.0
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Push : Yes
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun21
78.57.123.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
169.254.39.0    *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
78.57.120.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
default         78.57.123.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: When connecting two routers, TAP [Layer 2] is a better solution than TUN [Layer 3], and when using TAP, this issue shouldn't occur since TAP is essentially the same as running both routers to the same dumb switch. OEM firmware on routers routinely hobbles OpenVPN unless the WebUI offers the ability to paste in your own text config or the ability to connect to the router via SSH., so TAP is just a better option all around in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The client config needs to add a route for the server network that goes through the VPN:

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Your routing table has a route for 192.168.1.0 that goes through the gateway, which is incorrect.  Remove it.

Comment: Looks I can't edit routing tables on Asus router. I think I need `192.168.1.0   10.8.0.2` record in `Work` network which contains `192.168.0.0` net. `192.168.1.0` is in client

Comment: The client config is pushed to the PC by openvpn when it connects.  What is in the client config?

Comment: @stark The LAN route is already pushed to the client via the code box under _Work_ [`Push LAN to clients: Yes`]. The client config is not pushed to the PC by OpenVPN - that in and of itself is not only literally impossible, if it was possible it would be a security nightmare as the tunnel could not be trusted. The OpenVPN server can push a majority of the connection parameters to the client, however it cannot push all of them, the pushed parameters must be specified in the server config, and the client still requires a client config due to a handful of options that cannot be pushed.