# Routing tables in two routers connected with VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, asus, routing-table

I have two Asus routers connected via VPN over Internet. `Home` (VPN client) network is `192.168.0.0/24` and `Work` (VPN Server) network is `192.168.1.0/24`. More details [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1703195/vpn-connection-between-routers) .

Computers inside of each network can't see other side o VPN network.Trying to understand routing tables on each router:

Work:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun21
78.57.123.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
169.254.39.0    *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
78.57.120.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
default         78.57.123.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
```

Home:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
default         78.61.155.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun14
78.61.152.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
78.61.155.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
239.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
```

Trying to reach PC on Home network from Work Network:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.100 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.0.1]
  2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.8.0.6
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

According to my understanding first line means packet goes to Work router which is OK
Line 2 means packet is passed to `10.8.0.6` interface. But I don't see such IP in any of both tables? Which router owns `10.8.0.6` ? According to my understanding it must go through `10.8.0.2`. What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions regarding the same/similar issue

Comment: As I [mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1703195/vpn-connection-between-routers#comment2622501_1703195) on the original question, you would be better off configuring this as TAP [Layer 2], not TUN [Layer 3], as TUN works best for connecting remote endpoints, whereas TAP works best for connecting two or more routers, as TAP will transparently route between the two routers, analogous to running an ethernet cable between a LAN port of router 1 to a LAN port of router 2 where router 2 has a vLAN configured on that ethernet port.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VPN connection between routers](https://superuser.com/questions/1703195/vpn-connection-between-routers)

Comment: By configuring TUN, it allows Router 1 [Work] to communicate with the LAN IP of Router 2 [Home] - that's it, connection completed _(works well for accessing services running on Router 2 - WebUI, network share server, SSH server, etc. - but little else)_. To communicate with downstream devices of Router 2, DNAT rules must be implemented for traffic both ways, which is simply inefficient and not sane networking when TAP exists; this also doesn't allow communicating with devices downstream of Router 1, as it's not a client, but the server, which would require DNAT and SNAT rules on Router 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Line 2 means packet is passed to 10.8.0.6 interface. But I don't see such IP in any of both tables?

Not quite. It means the router at 10.8.0.6 *responded* to your packet, but doesn't say anything about how that packet was originally delivered to it.

As routers by their nature have multiple IP addresses, it is relatively common for a route to have one address as 'gateway', but for the actual gateway to send error responses using another.<sup>1</sup> It's still the same gateway.

Specifically with OpenVPN, previously the default configuration wasn't to use traditional "subnet" topology, instead the default was to imitate point-to-point /30 links. So the first client would be 10.8.0.1/30 (with the VPN server as 10.8.0.2), the second client would be 10.8.0.5/30 (with the VPN server as 10.8.0.6), the third client would be 10.8.0.9/30 (with the VPN server as 10.8.0.10)... and so on.

As you can see, with  clients, there would be  '/30' subnets and  addresses representing the same VPN gateway, and any one of them could potentially be picked for ICMP error responses (which is what 'traceroute' shows).

In most cases this doesn't matter; your lack of connectivity is caused by something else – perhaps the 'home' router's firewall rules are blocking the packets.

But if you specifically want subnet-style topology (where all clients have the same gateway address), you may be able to change the topology mode in the OpenVPN server's configuration, though there's no guarantee that ASUS exposes this option (it might be somewhere under "advanced").

---

<sup>1</sup> (And, as a related note, your VPN uses a `tun` interface – this is a "layer 3" tunnel which doesn't have MAC-layer addressing, which would be necessary for the routing table's "gateway" parameter to have any effect. This means that the route you have, "192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun21", has no way of actually requesting that the packet be delivered to 10.8.0.2 specifically – it'll just always go to whatever is on the other end of tun21.)

Comment: Net30 isn't applicable per the IP subnet of the VPN server [`192.168.0.0/24`]. Net30 was fully depreciated [2016.12.26](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/SupportedVersions) with the release of v2.4 - it was depreciated in v2.3, however it was left as the default [for](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Topology) "_...fear of breaking backwards-compat configs that rely on this behavior_".

Comment: @JW0914: That's not the VPN subnet, that's the LAN subnet. The VPN is 10.8.0.0/24, and the client IP addresses match the first two /30s out of that range (10.8.0.0/30 and 10.8.0.4/30).

Comment: Ah, I did misinterpret that to mean the IP subnet of the VPN server, although I'm not seeing the Net30 netmask [`255.255.255.252`]. To the OP's issue, they're trying to make TUN work where TAP should be being used, as TUN [Layer 3] is generally for connecting to endpoints, whereas TAP [Layer 2] is generally for connecting two or more routers together, allowing the routers to route traffic transparently between them as if they were connected to each other via an ethernet cable on the same LAN.

Comment: It won't be seen because it's configured as a PtP link (i.e. `10.8.0.8 peer 10.8.0.9` in iproute2 terms) resulting in /32 routes; the /30 is only the allocation.